# How to Bundle Name Vs Bundle Display Name Vs AppStoreConnect App Name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

I have little bit confusion about name pick when I submitting my App to AppStore..

I have Bundle Display Name in Xcode has KruchConnect but when I put same name in AppStoreConnect it saying that this App name is already taken ..

If I go with DKruchConnect it is taking the name but I have a Question Here if somebody download from App Store I want to show KruchConnect still Under App intead of DKruchConnect Is it possible ?

Answering my own Question ...

I read some where there is way If I put Bundle Name in info.plist file as KruchConnect it will display that name under App once i download from AppStore  is it correct ? If it is what happens that same already exits for other App too...is it legal ? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, yes.

Your App Store Connect name is how people will search and find you on the App Store.

Your Bundle Display Name is what will appear below the app icon on the screen.

To give an example, my application is called Charge Running. It's App Store Connect name is "Charge Running". However, that title is a bit to long for the home screen, so the bundle display name is "Charge".

App Store Connect names need to be unique. Bundle Display names do not need to be unique.

Comment: Thanks ..So that means even somebody put there app-display name as "Instagram" and App Store Connect name as "InstagramSomeCompanyname" is it legal and AppStore will it approve ?

Comment: Not exactly, intentionally trying to deceive a user is not something that is allowed on the App Store. Also, Instagram is trademarked, which can get you into other sorts of legal trouble.

Comment: k thanks .. but In my case Kruch Connect name already exists for couple of apps one among those is trademarked but there App Store Connect names different ..  my question is if even it's trademarked why other apps not changed to something else..? Also will they consider App Icon in those cases?